# Regular Expression for a phone number excluding special characters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I'm using a regular expression for a phone number. It allows at least 10 digits including special characters like +()-

```
+1(33)-489256
```

The Regular expression I am using is:

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){10,}$
```

It works OK but it should not allow other special characters in the phone number like #@$%

Please let me know how I can update my regex.

Comment: Can you add all possible valid formats of the phone numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){10,}$
         ^^
       [+()-]
```

just point out your regex problem

`\D`: any characters except digits

Comment: how would i write these regex... all in one line? My scenario for the phone number is that the user should be able to either enter just the plain phone number (should be a a minimum of 10 digits) like: 1234567899 or include these special character +()- in order to format the number +1(234)567-899 (BUT should not allow other special characters like @#$%

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your regex is `\D*`, this will match any **non-digit** characters(including special characters) any number of times.

Use

```
/^(\+\d{1,4})?(\d{2}\)-\d{6}$/
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/gP5zU3/3)

1. `/`: Delimiters of regex literal
2. `^`: Starts with anchor
3. `\+\d{1,3}`: One to three digits after `+`
4. `\d`: Matches single digit
5. `\(`: Matches `(` literally
6. `\d{2}`: Matches exactly two digits
7. `\)`: Matches `)` literally
8. `-`: Matches `-` literally
9. `\d{6}`: Matches exactly six digits
10. `$`: Ends with anchor

**Live Demo**

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(\+\d{1,4})?\(\d{2}\)-\d{6}" />
```

Comment: That pattern makes all my phone numbers invalid. :-(

Comment: @RobG Can you please give me an example

Comment: Presumably the + is for country code and expects something like +1(23), which might be country followed by region. Andorra has a country code of 376, Anguilla 1264. The most robust phone number entry forms I've seen have country code as a separate field to phone number, and allow spaces for formatting (they can be stripped at the backend).

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the info. Updated

Comment: Hi Tushar, thanks for the response. My scenario for the phone number is that the user should be able to either enter just the plain phone number (a minimum of 10 digits) like: 1234567899 or include these special character +()- in order to format the number +1(234)567-899 (BUT should not allow other special characters like @#$% please reply

Comment: @theITvideos Try `/^\d{10,14}|((\+\d{1,4})?(\d{2}\)-\d{6})$/`